# Conditional Expectation of joint/(composite function?)

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I'm prepping for an exam and looking through previous exams I came across this question:

**Let $Z$ be a Poisson distributed stochastic variable with parameter
$Λ$. In turn, $Λ$ is a Poisson distributed stochastic variable with parameter
$\mu=2$. Compute $E[Z]$
(Hint: $Z|Λ=\lambda$~Po($\lambda$).)**

answer: $E[Z]=2$

My first step was:

$E[Z]= E\Big[E[Z\;|\;Λ]\Big]$

however I'm not at all sure how to proceed. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next step is to evaluate $E[Z|\Lambda]$. By the hint, given that $\Lambda=\lambda$ we know that $Z$ has a Poisson($\lambda$) distribution and therefore $E(Z|\Lambda=\lambda)=\lambda$ (since the mean of a Poisson distribution equals its parameter). Conclude $E(Z|\Lambda)=\Lambda$.

Comment: so, how did you concluded from the hint that E[Z|Λ] = λ = Λ? I didn't really follow hehe. is it a general poisson property?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ has $Po(\lambda)$ distribution, then $E(X)=\lambda$. For example see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Mean . So given $\Lambda=\lambda$, we know $E(Z)=\lambda$.